# Example of a Lebesgue unmeasurable function f such that f*f is Lebesgue measurable

Tags: measure-theory

Giv an example of a Lebesgue unmeasurable function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f^2$ is Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: Try using the indicator function over, say, the Vitali set, except define the function to be equal to $-1$ for all elements in $[0,1]$ not in the Vitali set.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be a non measurable set in $[0,1]$. Let $f = 1_A - 1_{A^c}$. Then $f$ is not measurable, but $f^2 = 1$ is.

Comment: Very elegant solution, thank you!

Comment: But...How do we know that $f$ is not measurable? $f=1$ if $x\in A$ and -1 if  $x\in A^c$

Comment: What would $f^{-1} \{ 1 \}$ be? Or $f^{-1} \{ -1 \}$?